# how can I use PropertyChangeListner in GWT? or is there any better way of doing it?

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, propertychangelistener

I am trying to get the upload progress information from a servlet in GWT but `SubmitCompleteHandler` returns after completion of the server upload and the response retuned by the servlet. 
Is it possible to get the upload progress using `PropertyChangeListener`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `PropertyChangeListener` to implement displaying of upload progress information. Here's the good [sample](http://www.adrianwalker.org/2011/03/gwt-file-upload-with-event-based.html).

For example I know that earlier Gmail had used SWFUpload for it. You can use it via [SWFUpload-GWT](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload-gwt/). The main advantage of this method is this doesn't require any special server code.

And take a look to these libraries:

- [GWTUpload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/). It's very easy to integrate and works properly in all browsers. It uses ajax requests to calculate progress.
- GWTCProgressBar widget in [GWTChismes](http://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/)
- [File uploader](https://github.com/kompot/gwtupld/) with some features
- [GwtSwfExt](http://code.google.com/p/gwtswfext/)

Comment: What if I use  ProgressListener from apache commons ?